# how to do Static External Files in jboss-EAP 6.0 server

Tags: tomcat, jboss-eap-6, static-files

i am able to do in Tomcat like the below example but not able to do in jboss-EAP (Enterprise Application Server)6.0 server. Could u please guys help me out on this ?
below code I am  configure inside server.xml the same thing i want to do in jboss EAP.
Tomcat server example: `<Context docBase="C:/Users/downloads/" path="/abc"/>`

This is required for storing the file in that path and displaying in browser while click one button

Comment: Sorry, badly tagged question. I'll retag for you. Keep in mind that tags are for where the propblem is, not to specify your environment. Officially the tomcat tag is wrong to, so it might get removed